# How to change this script into

Tags: php, html, css

Well i found this stream script but the actual design of the area that holds the data is in CSS. But i dont know css so I'm wondering if you could tell me how i could change it to HTML. I dont mean write the code again in HTML.. I mean show me where i can enter my HTML.

All scripts [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/simple-ajax-commenting-system/).

Script with css :

```
/* grab stuff */
    function get_posts($start = 0, $number_of_posts = 5) {
        /* connect to the db */
        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('draft2',$connection);
        $posts = array();
        /* get the posts */
        $query = "SELECT item_id, username, item_content ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $start,$number_of_posts";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            preg_match("/<p>(.*)<\/p>/",$row['post_content'],$matches);
            $row['post_content'] = strip_tags($matches[1]);
            $posts[] = $row;
        }
        /* return the posts in the JSON format */
        return json_encode($posts);
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>Create  a Twitter-Like "Load More" Widget Using CSS, HTML, JSON, and jQuery or MooTools Javascript</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #posts-container            { width:400px; border:1px solid #ccc; -webkit-border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius:10px; }
        .post                       { padding:5px 10px 5px 100px; min-height:65px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; background:url(dwloadmore.png) 5px 5px no-repeat; cursor:pointer;  }
        .post:hover                 { background-color:lightblue; }
        a.post-title                { font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; }
        a.post-title:hover          { text-decoration:underline; color:#900; }
        a.post-more                 { color:#900; }
        p.post-content              { font-size:10px; line-height:17px; padding-bottom:0; }
        #load-more                  { background-color:#eee; color:#999; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; padding:10px 0; cursor:pointer; }
        #load-more:hover            { color:#666; }
        .activate                   { background:url(loadmorespinner.gif) 140px 9px no-repeat #eee; }
    </style>
```

If you know how to do this will you please tell me :D

Comment: SO is not your crew of monkey coders.

Comment: Learning the necessary CSS is a better idea than styling HTML directly, so it might be a good idea to bite the bullet and spend the necessary time.

Comment: I was asking you to point something out for me.. i asked where do i write html in this script. You dont even have to write anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is just applying styles to html, if you want to add html to the form you should but it in the body tag. (by the way your link to the code is not working)